# Showing that a specific graph is not hamiltonian

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonicity

I am supposed to show that the following graph is not hamiltonian.
[image: Graph that is being looked at]

In the lecture I am attending to we have looked at only one criteria to determine if a graph is not hamiltonian which is that for $\kappa(G-S) \leq |S|$ for any subset $S \subseteq V(G)$ for a hamiltonian graph.

Furthermore I have seen some other criteria of parts of graphs on which one might be able to determine that no hamilton circle can exist however I was not able to apply them to this graph.

Any hints/tips would be greatly appreciated

Comment: It’s not bad to do this one directly.  You can condition on which pair of the top edges you include.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I was able to do it with 9 different cases excluding the symmetries. Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you number the nodes from top to bottom and left to right, then $S=\{1,5,6,7,11\}$ certifies that $G$ is not Hamiltonian.  Removing $S$ (the red x nodes below) yields $6$ connected components (which happen to have one node each), so $\kappa(G-S) = 6 > 5 = |S|$.
[image]

Comment: Oh wow. That's very elegant. Thank you very much.